# $GET is array(0) after GET request (PHP)

Tags: php

Is it normal, that I never get url from $_GET['url'] every time I type url to the browser? I am unable to get url from $_GET['url'] even when I try to catch it in some class, but for simplicity i put it here just in this simple example.

[image]

```
<?php 
   $url = getUrl();

   function getUrl(){
    if(isset($_GET['url'])){
      $url = rtrim($_GET['url'], '/');
      $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
      $url = explode('/', $url);
      return $url;
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: That's not how `$_GET` works. Look into `parse_url()`.

Comment: In fact, $_GET works in this way when .htaccess is set in this way. That was the reason why I expected this behaviour here :-) When i fixed .htaccess i started getting url parts again. But thanks to everyone for your responses, I am php beginner and you helped me to find the cause.

Comment: So be fair and write an answer to your question explaining what had to be done to get it working. Maybe update your question to make a useful example, too.

Comment: U. Windl: I have just posted my answer. Question may be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$_GET` contains the parsed query parameters, not the actual URL itself.

You can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` to get the server's host name (ie. `host.example.com`, and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get the path (ie `/my/page/hello.php?a=b`).

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET` is used to get the URL params, and NOT the URL itself, use  **atymic** Answer to get what do you need

Answer (score 0):

What helped me was .htaccess file setting. In this way (see picture) i can catch url parts. So correct .htaccess setting was the best answer I think. Now it behaves as I expected.

[image]
.htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options -Multiviews
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /test
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]  
</IfModule>
```